# How to store sum(field_name) in a variable within MySql Select statement?

Tags: mysql, variables, select

I am trying to store the sum total of a particular field in a variable like `@data := sum(field_name)` within MySQL Select statement.

Below is an exact example of my query:

```
SELECT a.id, @data1:=sum(b.amount) amount, @data1 as returned_val
FROM tbl_table1 a 
LEFT JOIN tbl_table2 b ON b.acount_id=a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Notice that I store the `sum(b.amount)` to a variable `@data1` and tried to display it in another row but never work as what I'm expecting.

Is there any other way doing this?

Comment: Could you please include, what you're expecting?

Answer (score 5):

Do not use variables in SELECT statement with GROUP BY clause.

From the documentation:

> Note: In a SELECT statement, each expression is evaluated only when
>   sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY
>   clause, you cannot refer to an expression that involves variables that
>   are set in the SELECT list.

Use subquery to achieve this -

```
SELECT t.id, @data1:=t.amount, @data1 AS returned_val FROM (
    SELECT a.id, SUM(b.amount) amount
    FROM tbl_table1 a 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_table2 b ON b.acount_id=a.id
    GROUP BY a.id
  ) t
```

Comment: Nice solution. What's the performance cost of the sub select?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable first.

```
SET @data1=0;

SELECT a.id, (@data1:=sum(b.amount)) as amount, @data1 as returned_val
FROM tbl_table1 a 
LEFT JOIN tbl_table2 b ON b.acount_id=a.id
```

But why do you need the `returned_val` since it is the same value with `amount`.

Comment: Thanks xdazz but I tried it already and it doesn't work. Actually, it will work even you don't declare the variable without the "sum" function like