# How to optimize this MySQL real time item stock quantity query

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I have case in Pharmacy Warehouse which have Thousand-Million record of transaction of Stock Move
in last 3 years From 2018.

I Use MySQL and PHP in this case. Below is the table scheme.

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `ID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ITEM_CODE` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ITEM_NAME` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `ID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LOCATION_NAME` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `stock_move` (
  `ID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MOVE_TIME` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `MOVE_TIPE` ENUM('in','out') DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCATION_ID` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `stock_move_line` (
  `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `STOCK_MOVE_ID` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ITEM_ID` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTY` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `receipt` (
  `ID` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LOCATION_ID` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RECEIPT_TIME` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSON` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `receipt_line` (
  `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RECEIPT_ID` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ITEM_ID` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTY` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO item (ITEM_CODE, ITEM_NAME)
VALUES 
('PA03', 'Paracetamol Tablet 100 mg'),
('PA04', 'Paracetamol Tablet  500 mg (pamol)'),
('PA05', 'Paracetamol Drop'),
('PA06', 'Paracetamol Syrup 120 mg / 5 ml (pamol)');

INSERT INTO location (LOCATION_NAME)
VALUES 
('Clinic A'), ('Clinic B');

INSERT INTO stock_move (MOVE_TIME,MOVE_TIPE,LOCATION_ID)
VALUES 
('2018-01-01 07:30:00','in','1'),
('2019-07-15 09:45:00','out','1'),
('2018-01-01 07:30:00','in','2'),
('2019-07-15 09:45:00','out','2');

INSERT INTO stock_move_line (STOCK_MOVE_ID,ITEM_ID,QTY)
VALUES 
('1','2','100'),
('1','3','75'),
('1','4','50'),
('2','2','10'),
('2','3','2'),
('2','4','3'),
('3','2','40'),
('3','3','60'),
('3','4','20'),
('4','2','9'),
('4','3','12'),
('4','4','14');

INSERT INTO receipt (RECEIPT_TIME,LOCATION_ID,PERSON)
VALUES 
('2018-01-01 07:30:00','1','John S.'),
('2019-07-15 09:45:00','1','Clara R.'),
('2018-06-08 07:30:00','2','Anthony J.'),
('2019-09-23 09:45:00','2','Sheila W.');

INSERT INTO receipt_line (RECEIPT_ID,ITEM_ID,QTY)
VALUES 
('1','2','15'),
('1','3','9'),
('1','4','7'),
('2','2','10'),
('2','3','2'),
('2','4','3'),
('3','2','18'),
('3','3','4'),
('3','4','6'),
('4','2','3'),
('4','3','8'),
('4','4','1');
```

I wrote this query to get search item and get real time stock qty. This query reads quantity from warehouse and from receipt on each locations.

```
SELECT
i.ITEM_CODE,
i.ITEM_NAME,
sitmv.IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
sitmv.OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
sri.OUT_RECEIPT_QTY,
(sitmv.IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY-(sitmv.OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY + sri.OUT_RECEIPT_QTY)) AS REAL_QTY
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT
  sml.ITEM_ID,                                    
  SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE='in',sml.QTY,0)) AS IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
  SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE='out',sml.QTY,0)) AS OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY
  FROM stock_move_line sml
  INNER JOIN item i ON (i.ID=sml.ITEM_ID)
  INNER JOIN stock_move sm ON (sm.ID=sml.STOCK_MOVE_ID )                    
  WHERE sm.LOCATION_ID='1'AND sm.MOVE_TIME<='2020-10-21 23:59:59' AND ( i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%')
  GROUP BY sml.ITEM_ID
) sitmv ON (sitmv.ITEM_ID=i.ID)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
  rl.ITEM_ID,                  
  SUM(rl.QTY) AS OUT_RECEIPT_QTY
  FROM
  receipt_line rl
  INNER JOIN receipt r ON (r.ID=rl.RECEIPT_ID)
  INNER JOIN item i ON (i.ID=rl.ITEM_ID)  
  WHERE r.LOCATION_ID='1' AND r.RECEIPT_TIME<='2020-10-21 23:59:59' AND ( i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%')
  GROUP BY
  rl.ITEM_ID 
)sri ON (sri.ITEM_ID=i.ID)
WHERE ( i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%')
ORDER BY i.ITEM_NAME ASC  
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The operator user which use this app and run this is hundreds in same time same second is hundreds make this query run very slow.

The query show 4 row record result with execute time is more than 30s and sometimes in minutes or timeout in work hour and below 10s after work hour.

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------+
| ITEM_CODE |                ITEM_NAME                | IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY | OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY | OUT_RECEIPT_QTY | REAL_QTY |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------+
| PA05      | Paracetamol Drop                        | 336              | 249               | 92              | -5       |
| PA06      | Paracetamol Syrup 120 mg / 5 ml (pamol) | 3720             | 1032              | 1429            | 1259     |
| PA04      | Paracetamol Tablet  500 mg (pamol)      | 106134           | 12901             | 61172           | 32061    |
| PA03      | Paracetamol Tablet 100 mg               | NULL             | NULL              | NULL            | NULL     |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+----------+
```

How to optimize execute speed time in that query. Any help?

Also is there any recommendation or suggestion of better schema or structure to handle million record of running stock item quantity transaction like this case?

i'm avoiding to break the stock quantity valuation into periode like **YEAR** and **MONTH** beacuse i saw in app like **ODOO** use running valuation stock quantity approach like schema structure above.

Comment: one thing, you can definitely remove `locations` table from both of the subqueries.

Comment: locations is needed to calculate qty stock in location which operator user sign in. so different location different qty on those items

Comment: but that is already present in `receipt ` and `stock_move_line` table and you're not fetching anything from `locations` table.

Comment: i already tried to remove join on location in subquery not much different in performance

Comment: The best part would be trying with `EXPLAIN` in your query and check on which columns we can do an `index` to make this query faster.

Comment: try below concept `SELECT 
 col1,
 col2,
 ...
 (subquery 2 USING correlated concept) AS OUT_RECEIPT_QTY
 other COLUMNS
 
FROM item
LEFT JOIN stock_move_line sml -- use location filter here
LEFT JOIN stock_move   -- use move_time filter here
WHERE -- use item filter here.
GROUP BY item.id`

Answer (score 1):

You have two many-to-many mapping tables with no useful indexes.  Fix them.  Get rid of `id` and have a 2-column `PRIMARY KEY` and a 2-column secondary `INDEX`.  Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Try to avoid `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.  Neither of those "derived" tables has an index, hence performance will be poor.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the whole query.

`OR` is hard to optimize.  Leading wildcard cannot use an index

```
    i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%'
 OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%'
```

Consider adding `FULLTEXT(item_name, item_code)` and changing to

```
    MATCH(item_name, item_code) AGAINST("+PARACETAMOL" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

What version of MySQL are you using?  MySQL 8.0 has some new features that might help.

Comment: i know i must use `UNION` instead using `OR` in __Wildcard__. thank for suggestions.

Comment: `UNION` doesn't help -- because the leading wildcard prevents the use of an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a separate table of, say, item_drug(item_id,drug_id) and another table of drugs (drug_id,drug) such that you could search for 'PARACETAMOL' instead of '%PARACETAMOL%', this would greatly improve performance.

Also, remove the inverted commas around '35'.

For further tweaks, provide the EXPLAIN for this new query

Comment: sorry there's a typo in the query in smm.MOVE_TIME<=...

Comment: sadly there's only 1 `item` table for search in column `ITEM_NAME` and `ITEM_CODE`

Comment: Well, it's your schema now.

Comment: my task is to improve the performance of those query. i'm not allowed to change the schema beacuse it already had a million of data record. it designed by another enginer which is not in my workplace anymore

Comment: So you want to improve performance but you're not allowed to undertake the steps that would improve performance. I don't know what we're supposed to do with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something but if @Strawberry is pointing out then you must be looking for.

And the concept I was telling about is something like this.

```
SELECT
    i.ITEM_CODE,
    i.ITEM_NAME,
    SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE = 'in', sml.QTY, 0)) AS IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
    SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE = 'out', sml.QTY, 0)) AS OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
    ( SELECT SUM(rl.QTY) 
        FROM receipt_line rl
        INNER JOIN receipt r ON (r.ID=rl.RECEIPT_ID)
        WHERE i.ID=rl.ITEM_ID AND r.LOCATION_ID= 1 AND r.RECEIPT_TIME<='2020-10-21 23:59:59'
    ) AS OUT_RECEIPT_QTY
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN stock_move_line sml ON i.ID = sml.ITEM_ID 
LEFT JOIN stock_move sm ON sm.ID = sml.STOCK_MOVE_ID AND sm.MOVE_TIME <= '2020-10-21 23:59:59' AND sm.LOCATION_ID = 1
WHERE i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%'
GROUP BY i.ID;
```

The result is something like below.

```
| ITEM_CODE | ITEM_NAME                               | IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY | OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY | OUT_RECEIPT_QTY |
| --------- | --------------------------------------- | ---------------- | ----------------- | --------------- |
| PA03      | Paracetamol Tablet 100 mg               | 0                | 0                 | null            |
| PA04      | Paracetamol Tablet  500 mg (pamol)      | 100              | 10                | 25              |
| PA05      | Paracetamol Drop                        | 75               | 2                 | 11              |
| PA06      | Paracetamol Syrup 120 mg / 5 ml (pamol) | 50               | 3                 | 10              |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4QdB6xsc79HawALzoPYmL/1)

Comment: ok let me try this and check it performance. btw right now is after work hour in my place. so the query is much faster than in work hour with hundred or more user operator. and i'm also gonna try to check this query in work hour tomorrow hopefuly it give much better performance

Comment: i found in your query miss column to calculate `REAL_QTY` which is shown in my query and it's dificcult for me to modified Column to Calculate `REAL_QTY` with your query because the `SUM IF` Column and the `Subquery` Column become an _ALIAS_

Comment: you can assign it to a user defined variable and use it again like `@out_q := subquery as OUT_RECEIPT_QTY,  IN - (OUT + @out_q)`. You can also use alias for other two values or use direct `SUM clause`. If you are using some programming language like php, they can do it, they have the required data.

Comment: can you write those in _SQL TEXT_ ? i don't know how define variable in MYSQL. if i calculate those column in php script then i must update my code several line in different place of file script which is i avoided. also in your query the `GROUP BY` must be set to all column which is called in `SELECT`. i'm afraid the `item table` will be update with few more Column in the future. right now it's just `ITEM_CODE` and `ITEM_NAME` which need to be shown to User.

Comment: the column `REAL_QTY` from defined variable calculation show incorrect result value. and the value which shown is became same on different item which not to be expected. i found this post which discuss about not to use defined variable in `GROUP BY` query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578298/how-to-store-sumfield-name-in-a-variable-within-mysql-select-statement

Comment: After run sample result from your query it only shows 3 row. The item which dosn't have stock qty is not shown **ITEM_CODE**: `PA03` beacuse the `LEFT JOIN` to `stok_move_line`. This is also unexpected because the operator still need those item to be shown wether it have qty stock or not.

Comment: @lontonglemper, please create a [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) with table create code & some data using insert queries, so i can verify.

Comment: this is my sample in db_fiddle with my query and your query. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4QdB6xsc79HawALzoPYmL/0

Comment: I think only `real_qty` column in not populated, other than that everything is working fine.

Comment: i add answer with modified and simplified version of your query. with __sub select query__ please take a look at my answer somewhere in this post

Answer (score 0):

I also try to simplified @Jitendra Yadav Query with this query below which less complicated.

```
SELECT its.ITEM_CODE, its.ITEM_NAME, (its.IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY-its.OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY-its.OUT_RECEIPT_QTY) AS REAL_QTY
FROM(
SELECT
    i.ITEM_CODE,
    i.ITEM_NAME,
    SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE = 'in', sml.QTY, 0)) AS IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
    SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE = 'out', sml.QTY, 0)) AS OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
    ( SELECT SUM(rl.QTY) 
        FROM receipt_line rl
        INNER JOIN receipt r ON (r.ID=rl.RECEIPT_ID)
        WHERE i.ID=rl.ITEM_ID AND r.LOCATION_ID= 1 AND r.RECEIPT_TIME<='2020-10-21 23:59:59'
    ) AS OUT_RECEIPT_QTY    
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN stock_move_line sml ON i.ID = sml.ITEM_ID 
LEFT JOIN stock_move sm ON sm.ID = sml.STOCK_MOVE_ID AND sm.MOVE_TIME <= '2020-10-21 23:59:59' AND sm.LOCATION_ID = 1
WHERE i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%'
GROUP BY i.ID
)its;
```

Show Result:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+
| ITEM_CODE  |                ITEM_NAME                 | IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY  | OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY  | OUT_RECEIPT_QTY  | REAL_QTY |
+------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+
| PA03       | Paracetamol Tablet 100 mg                |                0  |                 0  | null             | null     |
| PA04       | Paracetamol Tablet 500 mg (pamol)        |              100  |                10  | 25               | 65       |
| PA05       | Paracetamol Drop                         |               75  |                 2  | 11               | 62       |
| PA06       | Paracetamol Syrup 120 mg / 5 ml (pamol)  |               50  |                 3  | 10               | 37       |
+------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+----------+
```

In Real Time Production DB it takes execute times (5,5 seconds)/always more than 5 seconds in after work hour condition.

Compare to this:

```
SELECT
i.ITEM_CODE,
i.ITEM_NAME,
sitmv.IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
sitmv.OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
sri.OUT_RECEIPT_QTY,
(sitmv.IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY-(sitmv.OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY + sri.OUT_RECEIPT_QTY)) AS REAL_QTY
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT
  sml.ITEM_ID,                                    
  SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE='in',sml.QTY,0)) AS IN_WAREHOUSE_QTY,
  SUM(IF(sm.MOVE_TIPE='out',sml.QTY,0)) AS OUT_WAREHOUSE_QTY
  FROM stock_move_line sml
  INNER JOIN item i ON (i.ID=sml.ITEM_ID)
  INNER JOIN stock_move sm ON (sm.ID=sml.STOCK_MOVE_ID )                  
  INNER JOIN location l ON (l.ID=sm.LOCATION_ID  )
  WHERE sm.LOCATION_ID='1' AND sm.MOVE_TIME<='2020-10-21 23:59:59' AND ( i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%')
  GROUP BY sml.ITEM_ID
) sitmv ON (sitmv.ITEM_ID=i.ID)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
  rl.ITEM_ID,                  
  SUM(rl.QTY) AS OUT_RECEIPT_QTY
  FROM
  receipt_line rl
  INNER JOIN receipt r ON (r.ID=rl.RECEIPT_ID)
  INNER JOIN item i ON (i.ID=rl.ITEM_ID)
  INNER JOIN location l ON (l.ID=r.LOCATION_ID)
  WHERE r.LOCATION_ID='1' AND r.RECEIPT_TIME<='2020-10-21 23:59:59' AND ( i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%')
  GROUP BY
  rl.ITEM_ID 
)sri ON (sri.ITEM_ID=i.ID)
WHERE ( i.ITEM_NAME LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%' OR i.ITEM_CODE LIKE '%PARACETAMOL%')
ORDER BY i.ITEM_NAME ASC  
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Anyway my first asked question query above before takes execute times (4,8 seconds)/always less than 5 seconds also in after work hour condition which is much faster than @Jitendra Yadav query.

Don't try in work hour condition yet maybe tomorrow.

Comment: i just wanna share my latest running test with **@Jitendra Yadav** query it takes __(29 seconds)__ and __(45 seconds)__ on second run with 4 row result. i compare running test with **my query that i asked first in this topic to optimize even before any update** is still running faster execute time with only __(9 seconds)__ on first run and __(28 seconds)_on second run. Still i hope it can run in __millisec__ consider the trasanction will become much bigger in the future.